# How to print brackets in python

Tags: python, printing, brackets

i want to print "(" in python

> print "(" + var + ")"

but it says:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

can somebody help me? that cant be too hard... -.-

Comment: why don't you do: `print "(%s)" % var`?

Comment: var is None, you should do what equinoxel said

Comment: these are NOT brackets.  these are parentheses.  VERY important distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`string formatting`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
foo = 'Hello'
print('({})'.format(foo))
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe a simple `print "(" + str(var) + ")"`?

Answer (score 1):

it appears that `var` is `None` in what you provided.  Everything is correct, but `var` does not contain a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var = 'Hello World!'
print('(' + var + ')')
```

Also, your code works well on `Python 2.7.4`, so long as you pre-define `var`.